# How do I import an array from a .js file into an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I'm new to JS and HTML, and for an assignment, I was given `stocks.js` containing an array:

```
'use strict';

const stocks = [
    { company: 'Splunk', symbol: 'SPLK', price: 137.55 },
    { company: 'Microsoft', symbol: 'MSFT', price: 232.04 },
    { company: 'Oracle', symbol: 'ORCL', price: 67.08 },
    { company: 'Snowflake', symbol: 'SNOW', price: 235.8 },
    { company: 'Terradata', symbol: 'TDC', price: 44.98 }
];

module.exports.stocks = stocks;
```

I'm supposed to use this array in another static HTML page I make, `stocklist.html`,  to make a table with all the data from `stocks.html`. So far I have:

```
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <caption><h1>Stock List</h1></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Company |</th>
                    <th>Symbol |</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id = "stockTable">

            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script>
            const { stocks } = require('./stocks.js');
            buildTable(stocks);
    
            function buildTable(data) {
                var table = document.getElementById("stockTable")
    
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var row = 
                        `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].company}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].symbol}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].price}</td>
                        </tr>`
                    table.innerHTML += row;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I just copy and paste the array `stocks` from `stocks.js` into the `<script>` element, the table is created just fine. Given the assignment's requirements, however, I can't do that, and I also can't edit `stocks.js`. How do I import the `stocks` array from `stocks.js` into `stocklist.html` so that I can access with `buildTable`?

Edit: My uneditable package.json file I was given for the assignment.

```
{
  "name": "assignment3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just edit add this line above of your buildTable() function.
<script type="text/javascript" src="stocks.js"></script>
Am I right?

Comment: I tried putting `<script type="text/javascript" src="stocks.js"></script>` between the lines `buildTable(stocks)` and `function buildTable(data)`  and unfortunately it just gave me an error as no matter where I put it, it's associating the `</script>` from the line you gave me with the `<script>` from my original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're exporting the array as a CJS module, I suggest that you check a [CommonJS (CJS) modules documentation](https://flaviocopes.com/commonjs/)

Furthermore, in your case, you can just require the module that your stocks.js are exporting. Like this:

```
const { stocks } = require('path/to/socks.js')
```

Comment: So I've tried putting the line `const stocks = require('stocks.js')` right above the line `buildArray(stocks)` in my HTML body which I would think would work as `stocks.js` and `stocklist.html` are both in the root directory, but I'm not seeing any changes. Am I inserting it into the correct place?

Comment: You need to add this code in your `stocklist.html` `<script>` tag.

Comment: `<script> const stocks = require('stocks.js'); buildTable(stocks); //rest of the code  </script>` For reference, I inserted it right about here, but saw no change. Apologies for sloppy formatting.

Comment: Indeed there's a mistake. This `require('stocks.js')` will return a object, and inside of this object is where your stocks array will be.

Comment: Try to do with the actual example. I've edited the original answer

Comment: As you've suggested, I edited the example in the question to reflect the change I made after I read your comment. Unfortunately, however, it's still not working and I have no clue what to do. It feels like it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Your browser's console isn't throwing any error?

Comment: It is throwing me an error, specifically "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined." I've updated the original question to include my package.json.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're running your project using the `start` command of your package, don't you?

Comment: Yes. After moving `stocks.js` and `package.json` into the directory I made for this project, I did `npm install`, and now whenever I start the server I use `npm start`. Whenever I run the run and debug the program with F5 in Visual Studio Code, it successfully opens up a web browser and displays the HTML elements I have, (table header, thead, etc), but not the data from `stocks.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your code directly into the script tag. You could use the script tag to import your js file. Like so :

```
<script src="./stocks.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

EDIT: Okay, that was not what I understood. To import javascript into another javascript. You can add `let stocksArray = require("./stocks.js");` at the top of your file, and then you have access to your stocks array.

Comment: If by this you mean add everything from the `<script>` element from `stocklist.js` into `stocks.js`, I can't. I forgot to mention in the original post that `stocks.js` is not allowed to be edited; fixed that.

Comment: @FujiHana I've edited the answer. I've missunderstood you at first but now it should match your requirement

Comment: When you say "top of your file," do you mean in the header tag? I've tried putting the line `let stocks = require("./stocks.js")` in my header, as well as above the `buildTable(stocks)` line in the `<script>` in my body element, but neither have worked.